# What does it mean? "The red box is the bounding box for the full asset."

Tags: android, icons

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html#icon9) I read that: "... Android 2.3 ... The red box is the bounding box for the full asset."
and below said that there are two sizes of one icon:

> ```
> Full Asset: 24w x 38h px (preferred, width may vary)
> Icon: 24w x 24h px (preferred, width may vary)
> ```

So, what size should be an icon image in the end "Full Asset" or "Icon"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That mean you should use a 24x38 image.
But you should leave 7px on top and bottom transparent.